# Is this valid footing?

Tags: deck, footings

I am buying a house ( new construction ) in Atlanta Georgia. Closing is not yet done. The builder is arguing an inspection point (the independent inspector was hired by me to check the construction completeness  ) that the Deck footing resting on a barrier wall is valid as it stands 3/4 or more on the wall. While the inspector told me, it has to be 100% on the wall.
Can someone confirm that 3/4 part of the footing, being on the wall is valid?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: the house is obviously leaning like the tower of Pizza, probably because of the footing

Comment: Whether it's code compliant or not,  I would have to wonder what other less-than-optimum (to be kind) things there are in that house that may not be visible.

Comment: The local building department inspector has the final say.  I would double check the rest of the house if the builder can make that mistake in simple measurements.  I imagine the deck was in the origin plans and not something added at the last minute.

Comment: The deck structure looks out of plumb... is this due to skew of the camera or does the post in question really lean back to rest on the cement wall like I'm seeing? And what's the story with the uneven bracing between the three posts? Does the builder consider this done, or is it temporary bracing?

Comment: All kinds of nopedy-nope-nope from my perspective on that footing location.  In addition, it looks from your far-away picture that the post is even leaning towards that spot, as though if it were really vertical, it wouldn't even be hitting that footing at all.  Send your pictures to the local municipality building inspector and see what they have to say.

Comment: Take a long hard look at what it will cost you to get the heck out of the as yet unclosed "deal." If the exposed work is this sloppy, the nightmares you haven't found yet are probably worse.

Comment: As for the last picture, I would not trust what I was seeing.  I have seen pictures on here of fasteners that changed from bring indented to bring raised.  I did not know if it was a phillips or a raised cross, each time I saw the picture it was different.  Pictures are good, but they can lie.

Comment: Slap a level (in the "looking for plumb" direction) on two adjacent faces of each of those porch posts to sort out if we have "optical fakes" or "really way out of plumb posts."

Comment: That picture looks awful but I also think it's fooling us. I'd love to see a level on the two perpendicular faces of that post. Regardless, the footing should be under the post.

Comment: I have doubts there's 75% bearing (if that's even true - haven't found anything aloowing less than full bearing in IRC code yet) given that it is hanging off on **two** sides. Accurate measurements of the overall size and the overhangs would confirm. Best I can tell from the pictures it might be as little as 60% total.

Comment: Properly speaking, this can be fixed by pouring more post base, (rebar to tie new to old). I'd be concerned that the anchor holding the ABA down is too close to the edge of the concrete. If you're going to get the building department involved, make sure they put their conclusions in writing.

Comment: Jeez, not only is the post only 75% on the wall, it's been made crooked to get that 75%.